# Shiny application using less if else statements with Plotly

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have Shiny Application that I build that displays Proxy Rankings by user over time.  The Shiny Application has a drop down where you can choose a user then a new line graph with that users data will be graphed.  However the code below was tested on only five users which isn't a pain to code.  But I would like to have thousands of users available.  Is there a better way to tweak this code so that I don't have to add separate Plotly graphs in the code for each user?

Sample of Data:

```
    devicereceipttime           sourceusername  GlobalRank
0   2018-12-04T09:26:54.000Z    1111            8507790
1   2018-12-04T09:27:05.000Z    2222            2648
2   2018-12-04T09:27:05.000Z    3333            156433
3   2018-12-04T09:27:10.000Z    5555            295
4   2018-12-04T17:14:51.000Z    1111            1
5   2018-12-04T17:14:51.000Z    4444            1
6   2018-12-04T17:15:11.000Z    2222            373436
7   2018-12-04T17:15:20.000Z    1111            250639
8   2018-12-04T17:15:32.000Z    1111            1
9   2018-12-04T17:15:38.000Z    2444            2965900
10  2018-12-04T17:16:00.000Z    2222            250639
11  2018-12-04T10:52:17.000Z    1111            799963
12  2018-12-04T10:52:26.000Z    3333            1
13  2018-12-04T10:52:26.000Z    1111            799963
14  2018-12-04T17:16:20.000Z    2222            250639
15  2018-12-04T10:52:26.000Z    4444            1
16  2018-12-04T10:52:27.000Z    4444            1
17  2018-12-04T10:52:26.000Z    1111            2648
```

Shiny R Code:

```
#Import libraries
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(bindrcpp)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- bootstrapPage(

  selectInput(inputId = "n_breaks",
              label = "Select Data:",
              choices = c("User1","User2","User3","User4","User5"),
              selected = "User1"),

  plotlyOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "500px")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a Line chart
server <- function(input, output) {

  #Import data
  df1 = read.csv("Data/all_5_test_users.csv")
  #Do cool things with the data
  df2 <- df1 %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -(devicereceipttime:sourceusername)) %>% 
    unite(temp, sourceusername, variable) %>% 
    group_by(temp) %>% 
    mutate(id=1:n()) %>% 
    spread(temp, value) 

  #Remove the id column
  df2 <- subset(df2, select = -c(id))
  #Remove "_GlobalRank" from titles
  names(df2) = gsub(pattern = "_GlobalRank*", replacement = "", x = names(df2)) 

  output$main_plot <- renderPlotly({

    if (input$n_breaks == "User1") {
      #Create variable X 
      x <- df2$devicereceipttime[!is.na(df2$`1111`)]
      #Create variable Y
      y <- df2$`1111`[!is.na(df2$`1111`)]
      #Plotly plot
      plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
        layout(
          margin = list(b = 190, l = 50)) # to fully display the x and y axis labels
    }
    else if (input$n_breaks == "User2") {
      #Create variable X 
      x <- df2$devicereceipttime[!is.na(df2$`2222`)]
      #Create variable Y 
      y <- df2$`2222`[!is.na(df2$`2222`)]
      #Plotly plot
      plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
        layout(
          margin = list(b = 190, l = 50)) # to fully display the x and y axis labels 
    }
    else if (input$n_breaks == "User3") {
      #Create variable X 
      x <- df2$devicereceipttime[!is.na(df2$`3333`)]
      #Create variable Y 
      y <- df2$`3333`[!is.na(df2$`3333`)]
      #Plotly plot
      plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
        layout(
          margin = list(b = 190, l = 50)) # to fully display the x and y axis labels  
    } 
    else if (input$n_breaks == "User4") {
      #Create variable X 
      x <- df2$devicereceipttime[!is.na(df2$`4444`)]
      #Create variable Y 
      y <- df2$`4444`[!is.na(df2$`4444`)]
      #Plotly plot
      plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
        layout(
          margin = list(b = 190, l = 50)) # to fully display the x and y axis labels  
    }
    else if (input$n_breaks == "User5") {
      #Create variable X 
      x <- df2$devicereceipttime[!is.na(df2$`5555`)]
      #Create variable Y 
      y <- df2$`5555`[!is.na(df2$`5555`)]
      #Plotly plot
      plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
        layout(
          margin = list(b = 190, l = 50)) # to fully display the x and y axis labels  
    }
  })   
}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Image of Shiny App]

**EDIT: I tried the following:**

```
#Import libraries

library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyr)
library(bindrcpp)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- bootstrapPage(

  selectInput(choices = c("User1" = "1111", "User2" = "2222", "User3" = "3333", "User4" = "4444", "User5" = "5555")),

  plotlyOutput(outputId = "main_plot", height = "500px")
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

  #Import data
  df1 = read.csv("Data/all_5_test_users.csv")
  #Do cool things with the data
  df2 <- df1 %>% 
    gather(variable, value, -(devicereceipttime:sourceusername)) %>% 
    unite(temp, sourceusername, variable) %>% 
    group_by(temp) %>% 
    mutate(id=1:n()) %>% 
    spread(temp, value) 

  #Remove the id column
  df2 <- subset(df2, select = -c(id))
  #Remove "_event_count_slc" from titles
  names(df2) = gsub(pattern = "_GlobalRank*", replacement = "", x = names(df2)) 

  output$main_plot <- renderPlotly({

    observeEvent(input$n_breaks,{
      #Create variable X 
      x <- df2$devicereceipttime[!is.na(df[[input$n_breaks]])]
      #Create variable Y
      y <- df[[input$n_breaks]][!is.na(df[[input$n_breaks]])]
      #Plotly plot
      plot_ly(x = x, y = y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
        layout(
          margin = list(b = 190, l = 50)) # to fully display the x and y axis labels  
      updatePlotly("your plot id")
      })
    })
  }  

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7673
Warning: Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'ggplotly' applied to an object of class "c('Observer', 'R6')"
Stack trace (innermost first):
    82: "plotly"::"ggplotly"
    81: func
    80: origRenderFunc
    79: output$main_plot
     4: <Anonymous>
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: <Promise>
Warning: Error in [[: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable



df2
# A tibble: 55,296 x 6
   devicereceipttime          `1111`  `2222`  `3333`  `4444`  `5555`
   <fct>                      <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>   <int>
 1 2018-12-04T00:00:00.000Z      0       1      0       0       0
 2 2018-12-04T00:00:05.000Z      0       1      0       0       0
 3 2018-12-04T00:00:24.000Z      0       1      0       0       0
 4 2018-12-04T00:00:26.000Z      0       1      0       0       0
 5 2018-12-04T00:00:45.000Z      0       1      0       0       0
 6 2018-12-04T00:00:50.000Z      0       1      0       0       0
 7 2018-12-04T00:01:00.000Z      0       1      0       0       0
 8 2018-12-04T00:01:26.000Z      0       1      0       0       0
 9 2018-12-04T00:01:45.000Z      0       1      0       0       0
10 2018-12-04T00:01:46.000Z      0       1      0       0       0
# ... with 55,286 more rows
```

The x axis is the date time and the y axis is the count of the user selected.

Comment: You will need a table linking sourceusernames to user ID, best to make a function then that you input `"User1"` and it outputs `"1111"` (output should be of character mode). Then use style of `df2[,"4444"]` instead of `df2$'4444'`., i.e. `df2[,my_function(input$n_breaks)]`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unless you want your dataset to be loaded each time some one loads your app, keep loading data outside both `server` and `Ui` functions.

To answer your question:

First, let the choices of your `selectInput` as key value to ease things for you, so you can use the value to be displayed and key in update later as follow:

```
choices = c("User1" = "1111","User2" = "2222","User3" = "3333")
```

in your case you have to get key/value from your dataframe ofcourse

Then, you can use `obserEvent` on your `selectInput` to update your plot using the new selected input as follow:

```
observeEvent(input$n_breaks,{
    #Create variable X 
  x <- df2$devicereceipttime[!is.na(df[[input$n_breaks]])]
  #Create variable Y
  y <- df[[input$n_breaks]][!is.na(df[[input$n_breaks]])]
    updatePlotly("your plot id")
    })
```

Comment: I have tried this but I am getting a few errors.  I added the code above.  Can you check it out @Mohammed Ali

Comment: The above is not the final code, may you  please add the final code and also print what `x` and `y` values are.. @sectechguy

Comment: I added the x and y values @Mohammed Ali

Comment: @sectechguy, I think the issue is in dataframe column names, as they are not standard `R` is appended an `X` to it, when I tried it I used ` y <- df1[[paste0("X",input$n_breaks)]]`  to index the data.
Also look at this advanced plotly example for more advanced example
https://plot.ly/r/datatable/